# Which algorithm or library can I use for detection and measuring box or boxes dimension

Tags: opencv, image-processing, visual-c++, 3d, realsense

I am currently working on a camera 3D realsense camera that detection and calculate the box or boxes dimension.

I am new in computer vision. I first worked on i just work on detection objects detection with color or without color to get a basic understanding. Using C++ and openCV, I want to  managed to get the corners (and their x y z pixel coordinates) of the square using smoothing (remove noise), edge detection (canny function), lines detection (Hough transform) and lines intersection (mathematical calculation) on an simplified picture (uniform background).

Now is my question: do you have any direction/recommendation/advice/literature about dimension calculation of box. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-i2E7aZY6A

i am using c++ and opencv with  Intel realsens  3D camera.
thanks  in advance((-_-))

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the colour image pixel coordinates of the box you can obtain the real-world coordinates (also known as vertices or camera coordinates in the documentation) using methods in the [projection interface](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?pxcprojection.html), then simple pythagoras to calculate the distance between the points in mm.

If you have no experience with RealSense I'd recommend reading [the documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?doc_devguide_introduction.html) and looking through the sample apps included with the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

With PCL (Point Cloud Library) you can find planes (or spheres and other surfaces), then refine the result with 2D image processing (eg. edge detection).

http://pointclouds.org/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VD044WAHEe4